# Embedding Rhino on Android Problems

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, rhino

When trying to add an object to the JS environment using Rhino 1.7 r2 on Android 2.2 I always get a NullPointerException. I have boiled the class down to the bare minimum to get this exception, and I can't figure out why. Here's the code that always produces the exception:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Rhino context object */
    private Context mCX;
    /** Rhino script scope object */
    private Scriptable mScope;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create our context and turn off compilation
        mCX = Context.enter();
        mCX.setOptimizationLevel( -1 );

        // Initialize the scope
        mScope = mCX.initStandardObjects();

        Object insertObj;

        // This line always throws the exception.
        insertObj = Context.javaToJS( this, mScope );

        // We never get here
        ScriptableObject.putProperty( mScope, "platform", insertObj );

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Changing the troublesome line to some else like `insertObj = Context.javaToJS( null, mScope );` or really anything but `this` and the problem doesn't occur.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  308): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me/com.me.StartActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.impl.MethodDescriptor.getInstance(MethodDescriptor.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.net.sf.retrotranslator.runtime.java.lang.reflect._Constructor.isVarArgs(_Constructor.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.jdk15.VMBridge_jdk15.isVarArgs(VMBridge_jdk15.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.init(MemberBox.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.<init>(MemberBox.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.reflect(JavaMembers.java:667)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.<init>(JavaMembers.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.JavaMembers.lookupClass(JavaMembers.java:838)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.initMembers(NativeJavaObject.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject.<init>(NativeJavaObject.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrapAsJavaObject(WrapFactory.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.WrapFactory.wrap(WrapFactory.java:105)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.javaToJS(Context.java:1698)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at com.me.android.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  308):    ... 11 more
```

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

**[EDIT]** After some serious googling and head smashing I discovered the `ScriptableObject.defineClass` method and tried using that instead, following the examples in the Rhino documentation, however now I get a RuntimeException "ReferenceError: 'DeviceInterface' is not defined." I know this is possible, as Rhino is what the [ASE](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) uses for its JavaScript support.

Here is the new code which throws the RuntimeException:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Rhino context object */
    private Context mCX;
    /** Rhino script scope object */
    private Scriptable mScope;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create our context and turn off compilation
        mCX = Context.enter();
        mCX.setOptimizationLevel( -1 );

        // Initialize the scope
        mScope = mCX.initStandardObjects();

        try{
            ScriptableObject.defineClass( mScope, DeviceInterface.class );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            Log.e("StartActivity", e.toString());
        }

        // This is the line that throws the exception
        mCX.evaluateString(mScope,
                "var p = new DeviceInterface();", "",
                1, null);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And the DeviceInterface class:

```
public class DeviceInterface extends ScriptableObject
{
    static private final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static public void init ( Scriptable scope )
    {
        Log.i( "JSInterface", "Init called" );
    }

    public DeviceInterface()
    {
        logger( "Created new JSInterface Object" );
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName()
    {
        return "DeviceInterface";
    }

    public void jsFunction_logger( String message )
    {
        logger( message );
    }

    private void logger( String message )
    {
        if( message.contains("[alrt]") )
            Log.e( "JSInterface", message );
        else if( message.contains("[info]") )
            Log.i( "JSInterface", message );
        else
            Log.d( "JSInterface", message );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried both of your examples:

- Your first example executes without any exception on my project (in debug mode under Eclipse with ADK plugin) - how did you embed the Rhino library? I have been content with "Configure Build Path…/Add External JAR…"
- Your second example throws the same exception on a standard JVM - meaning it's not an Android problem.

Comment: I added Rhino to the project the same way, using Eclipse I added an external JAR... and I don't believe it, now it works. What's that saying? "It's always broken until someone else tries it."

Comment: Nevermind. I think this source is compatible: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/rhino/rhino1_7R2.jar